# API метод, помеченный аннотацией @Throws, при вызове не требует обработки исключения

Tags: android, исключения, kotlin, retrofit2, android-annotations

Аннотация, которой я буду помечать каждый API метод. В ней указывается класс парсера:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Parser {
    Class<? extends BaseParser> value();
}
```

Абстракция парсера:

```
abstract class BaseParser<T>(private val htmlDocument: Document) {

    fun build(): SkyscrapersResponse<T> {
        return SkyscrapersResponse(getWicketCode(), parse())
    }

    private fun getWicketCode(): Int {
        val element = htmlDocument.selectFirst("a[href*=$WICKET_REF], form[action*=$WICKET_REF]")
                ?: return 0
        val linkWithWicket =
                if (element.tagName() == "a") element.attr("href")
                else element.attr("action")
        return linkWithWicket.firstAfter(WICKET_REF).split(":").firstNumber()
    }

    abstract fun parse(): T

    companion object {
        private const val WICKET_REF = "wicket:interface"
    }

}
```

Конвертер (обработка аннотации):

```
class TypeConverterFactory : Converter.Factory() {

    override fun responseBodyConverter(type: Type,
                                       annotations: Array<Annotation>,
                                       retrofit: Retrofit): Converter<ResponseBody, *>? {
        val parserAnnotation = annotations.firstOrNull { it.annotationClass == Parser::class }
        val parserClass = (parserAnnotation as Parser).value.javaObjectType
        return HtmlConverter(parserClass)
    }

    class HtmlConverter<T>(private val parserClass: Class<out BaseParser<T>>) :
            Converter<ResponseBody, SkyscrapersResponse<T>> {
        override fun convert(response: ResponseBody): SkyscrapersResponse<T> {
            val htmlDocument = Jsoup.parse(response.string())
            val parser = parserClass.getConstructor(Document::class.java).newInstance(htmlDocument)
            return parser.build()
        }
    }
}
```

Получается так, что у меня конвертер один, но работает он с разными парсерами. Чтобы не тянуть колбэк в конвертер, я решил, что ошибки я буду вызывать как свои исключения. Например, при парсинге HTML-страницы, загружаемой после отправки данных формы входа, я ищу текст "Неверный ник или пароль", и если такой есть, то я бросаю `WrongUserNickOrPasswordException` из парсера и уже отслеживаю исключение там, где вызываю апи метод. Получается, так будет идти мое исключение:

> LoginResultParser > TypeConverterFactory > ??? > вызывающий код

В итоге я решил пометить метод апи аннотацией @Throws:

```
@Throws(WrongNickOrPasswordException::class)
@Parser(LoginResultParser::class)
@Multipart
@POST("/login¿wicket:interface=:{wicketCode}:loginForm:loginForm::IFormSubmitListener::")
fun login(@QueryMap loginData: FormData): Call<SkyscrapersResponse<Home>>
```

Но при вызове метода Android Studio не предлагает мне обработать мое исключение.

- Как я могу сделать, чтобы @Throws работала в сгенерированном интерфейсе?
- Я вообще получу свое исключение, или ретрофит упадет?

Comment: Ретрофит не падает - он вызывает коллбэк `onFailure` и передаёт туда exception параметром `Throwable`

Comment: @woesss, ауч, да, точно! а если я использую execute, а не enqueue?

Comment: Не доводилось, но скорее всего тогда мы ловим exception сами (оборачиваем `execute` в `try-cath`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Kotlin аннотация `@Throws` нужна для Java кода, который будет использовать помеченный ей метод/конструктор. Если переписать мой `LoginResultParser` на Java, то IDE *потребует обработки исключения*.

Если же не переписывать класс на Java, то аннотация `@Throws` не нужна, так как в Kotlin нет checked-exceptions. Получается, что в этом случае мы должны помнить **сами** какие исключения могут выкинуться и если мы забудем сделать обработку, то получим *краш в рантайме*.

Я не буду холиварить на тему *checked VS unchecked*, но скажу, что выбрал unchecked вот почему:

- Все исключения штатные
- Переписывать на Java весь код парсера, уже написанный с kotlin extensions и лямбдами, не очень-то хочется :)

*P.S Но аннотацию `@Throws` я все-таки оставил, что-бы все исключения были "под рукой"*